# Как выровнять вложенные листы относительно внешних?

Tags: latex, разметка, дизайн, tex

Как в латехе выровнять внутренние листы относительно внешних? Т.е. чтобы чёрточки второго `itemize` были на уровне текста первого?

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item 1
  \begin{itemize}
    \item 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить `[left=0ex]` во вложенный `itemize`.